# Update of a table using subquery (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the following structure of my table:

```
    HID            TIME_FROM         LAG_TIME_FROM          TIME_UNTIL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAAAA12334566   06.07.19 04:04:51   13.07.19 04:05:17   13.07.19 04:05:17
AAAAA12334566   13.07.19 04:05:17   14.07.19 04:05:30   14.07.19 04:05:30
AAAAA12334566   14.07.19 04:05:30   23.07.19 22:00:00   23.07.19 22:00:00
AAAAA12334566   23.07.19 22:00:00   23.07.19 22:00:00   25.07.19 04:05:06
AAAAA12334566   23.07.19 22:00:00   25.07.19 04:05:06   22.07.19 22:00:00
AAAAA12334566   25.07.19 04:05:06   25.07.19 04:05:06   01.01.99 00:00:00
AAAAA12334566   25.07.19 04:05:06   01.01.99 00:00:00   24.07.19 04:05:06
BBBBBB12334566  29.06.18 14:59:20   01.02.19 14:25:00   01.02.19 14:25:00
BBBBBB12334566  01.02.19 14:25:00   07.03.19 04:07:48   07.03.19 04:07:48
BBBBBB12334566  07.03.19 04:07:48   05.07.19 04:04:47   09.07.19 04:04:52
BBBBBB12334566  05.07.19 04:04:47   06.07.19 04:04:51   09.07.19 04:04:52
BBBBBB12334566  06.07.19 04:04:51   08.07.19 13:00:45   09.07.19 04:04:52
BBBBBB12334566  08.07.19 13:00:45   08.07.19 13:18:19   12.07.19 04:04:44
```

Column `HID`,`TIME_FROM` and `TIME_UNTIL` exist in my table. The column `LAG_TIME_FROM` was generated by the following SQL statement and doesn't exist in the table:

```
Select HID, TIME_FROM, nvl(lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM),timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00')  LAG_TIME_FROM, TIME_UNTIL
from my_table
where HID in (

' AAAAA12334566 ',
' BBBBBB12334566 ',
' CCCCCC12334566 ',
' DDDDD12334566 ',
'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
'GGGGG12334566 ');
```

What I want to do is to update TIME_UNTIL column by the sql statement written above(LAG_TIME_FROM). here is my attempt:

```
    UPDATE my_table s1
    SET TIME_UNTIL= ( 

    select LAG_TIME_FROM from(
    select HID, TIME_FROM, nvl(lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM),timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00')  LAG_TIME_FROM, TIME_UNTIL
    from my_table
    ) s2 
    Where s1.HID in (
    ' AAAAA12334566 ',
    ' BBBBBB12334566 ',
    ' CCCCCC12334566 ',
    ' DDDDD12334566 ',
    'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
    'GGGGG12334566 ')
    and s1. hid = s2. hid
    and s1. TIME_FROM = s2.TIME_FROM
    and s1. TIME_UNTIL = s2. TIME_UNTIL
    );
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> ORA-01407: cannot update TIME_UNTIL to NULL.

I cannot understand why do I get NULLS, because when I run sql statement:

```
Select HID, TIME_FROM, nvl(lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM),timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00')  LAG_TIME_FROM, TIME_UNTIL
    from my_table
    where HID in (

    ' AAAAA12334566 ',
    ' BBBBBB12334566 ',
    ' CCCCCC12334566 ',
    ' DDDDD12334566 ',
    'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
    'GGGGG12334566 ');
```

everything looks perfectly fine

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You should strive to avoid redundancy in your database. It may be better to create a view, maybe a materialized one, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `nvl()` (or as I prefer, `coalesce()`) *outside* the subquery:

```
UPDATE my_table s1
    SET TIME_UNTIL = coalesce((select LAG_TIME_FROM
                               from (select t.*,
                                            lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM) as LAG_TIME_FROM
                                     from my_table t
                                    ) s2 
                               where s1.hid = s2. hid and
                                     s1.TIME_FROM = s2.TIME_FROM and
                                     s1. TIME_UNTIL = s2.TIME_UNTIL
                              ), timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00'
                             )
where s1.HID in (' AAAAA12334566 ',
                 ' BBBBBB12334566 ',
                 ' CCCCCC12334566 ',
                 ' DDDDD12334566 ',
                 'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
                 'GGGGG12334566 '
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one condition after your outer  select in update statement

```
     where LAG_TIME_FROM IS NOT 
    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Unformated, it is difficult to read so I formatted it a little bit.

```
UPDATE my_table s1
  SET TIME_UNTIL = 
    (select LAG_TIME_FROM 
     from (select HID, 
                  TIME_FROM, 
                  nvl(lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM), 
                      timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00'
                     ) LAG_TIME_FROM, 
                     TIME_UNTIL
           from my_table
          ) s2 
     Where s1.HID in (' AAAAA12334566 ',    --> are there really leading and
                      ' BBBBBB12334566 ',   --> trailing spaces here?
                      ' CCCCCC12334566 ',
                      ' DDDDD12334566 ',
                      'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
                      'GGGGG12334566 '
                     )
       and s1. hid = s2. hid                --> there shouldn't be any space between alias and
       and s1. TIME_FROM = s2.TIME_FROM     --> column names
       and s1. TIME_UNTIL = s2. TIME_UNTIL
    );
```

Are there really leading and trailing spaces in `IN` elements?

Other than that, it seems that you wanted to update only some `s1` rows, but your query is updating **all** of them - some of them to `NULL` so Oracle complains as column is most probably declared as `NOT NULL`.

It means that you have to restrict rows to be updated. Maybe moving `IN` clause out of subquery will help, e.g.

```
UPDATE my_table s1
  SET TIME_UNTIL = 
    (select LAG_TIME_FROM 
     from (select HID, 
                  TIME_FROM, 
                  nvl(lead(TIME_FROM) over(partition by HID order by TIME_FROM), 
                      timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00'
                     ) LAG_TIME_FROM, 
                     TIME_UNTIL
           from my_table
          ) s2 
     where 1 = 1                            --> placeholder for now missing IN clause
       and s1.hid = s2. hid                
       and s1.TIME_FROM = s2.TIME_FROM     
       and s1.TIME_UNTIL = s2. TIME_UNTIL
    )
Where s1.HID in (' AAAAA12334566 ',    --> are there really leading and
                 ' BBBBBB12334566 ',   --> trailing spaces here?
                 ' CCCCCC12334566 ',
                 ' DDDDD12334566 ',
                 'EEEEEEE12334566 ',
                 'GGGGG12334566 '
                );
```

See if it helps; if not, you'll have to fix it. How? You should know, you have the data. `EXISTS` clause usually helps in such cases.

Comment: *there shouldn't be any space between alias and column names* - @Littlefoot do you have some evidence for it in Oracle documentation or standard? Though maybe not *esthetic* the spaces seems to be completly OK: `select DUAL . DUMMY from dual`. If I interpret the [Column Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Column-Expressions.html#GUID-B16B2D82-5D4B-485B-AE20-160EC0C7137A) with your logik, the same argument would lead to only allowed usage of `1+1` and never `1 + 1` ...

Comment: Well, from my point of view, `e. ename` is quite different from `1 + 1`, @Marmite, but yes - today I learnt something new & exciting. True, it really works. Of course I don't have any evidence as there's none. I was simply thinking that space is *wrong*. Never even seen anyone writing it separated. Thank you so much for the tip, I'll fix my message.